# Distributing PlusMinus consistently

Tags: programming, syntax

I would like to give the built-in function `PlusMinus`, which is undefined by default, the intuitive meaning: considering all possible combinations of $+$ and $-$.

For simple expressions, this can be implemented as follows:

```
PlusMinus[a_,b_] := Flatten[{a+b,a-b}]
a \[PlusMinus] b \[PlusMinus] c
```

> ```
> {a+b+c, a-b+c, a+b-c, a-b-c}
> ```

However, there are of course more complicated examples, such as when $\pm$ appears in a function's argument, for example I would like to do the same thing for arbitrary (non-`listable`) functions $f(a\pm b\pm\cdots)$, which should by the same principle yield

> ```
> {f[a+b+...], f[a-b+...], ...}
> ```

To complicate things even further, consider

- $f(a\pm b, c)$
- $a+f(b+c\pm d,e)$
- $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$
- ...

Can this be implemented purely by giving `PlusMinus` the appropriate definitions?

Comment: However be aware that this is *not* the meaning most commonly assigned to it. Rather, in most cases $a\pm b\pm c$ is considered to be either $a+b+c$ or $a-b-c$. That's why there's a corresponding $\mp$ (`MinusPlus` in Mathematica): $a\pm b\mp c$ is either $a+b-c$ or $a-b+c$).

Comment: @celtschk I think your definition (the standard one) is more useful, but programming it seems *more* complicated, since you have to keep track of all the appearances of $\pm$ in an expression and change them consistently. I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my shot, haven't tested it much yet, but it's pretty weird.
Flattens out in NumericFunctions, I thought that made sense.

```
ClearAll[PlusMinus];
Module[{PlusMinusList},
 SetAttributes[PlusMinus, {Flat, OneIdentity, NumericFunction}];
 SetAttributes[PlusMinusList, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
 PlusMinus[a_] := PlusMinusList[a, -a];
 PlusMinus[a_, b_] := PlusMinusList[a + b, a - b];
 PlusMinusList /: 
  h_Symbol?(MemberQ[Attributes[#], NumericFunction] &)[b___, 
   pm_PlusMinusList, a___] := 
  Block[{PlusMinusList}, h[b, #, a] & /@ pm];
 PlusMinusList[exp___] := {exp} /; Length@Stack[] === 4;
 PlusMinusList /: 
  h_?(Head[#] =!= Symbol || ! 
        MemberQ[Attributes[#], NumericFunction] &)[bef___, 
   PlusMinusList[pm___], aft___] := 
  h[bef, {pm}, aft];
 ]
```

The idea is that it splits the results not in a regular List but in a PlusMinusList, which flattens itself out. With UpValues, it distributes over NumericFunctions. Then I put a couple of weird definitions to turn the PlusMinusList into a List in two cases: when it's already in the highest level of the stack, and when it is wrapped up by a non numeric function.
But I'm already seing that it doesn't Flatten properly nested PlusMinus because it doens't have the NumericFunction Attribute

**EDIT**

I added the attribute NumericFunction to PlusMinus, and removed the condition "/; h =!= PlusMinusList;" which I think serves no purpose. Also added a line to consider the single argument case PlusMinus[x]

Comment: $a+f(b\pm c)$ will result in `a + f[{b + c, b - c}]` :-(

Comment: @David, That's because it is set to distribute on NumericFunctions. I thought it was a good idea, otherwise it would end up doing big messes since you coundn't ever treat it as a list. Just before doign that do SetAttributes[f, NumericFunction] so MMA knows that it's a function that's supposed to return a numeric value if given numeric inputs

Comment: Ah, now it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to throw together sort of a solution. Note however that **this is not what I am looking for** (since I'm defining a helper function, whereas I would like the symbol itself to behave like this), the question remains open. However, I thought this might be useful for others nevertheless.

The algorithm works by searching all occurrences of `PlusMinus`, and replaces them with `Slot`. The resulting expression is then converted to a `Function`, and this function is applied to all the tuples of `Plus` and `Subtract` up to the length of how many `PlusMinus` there were in the first place.

```
distributePlusMinus[expression_] := Module[{count, tuples, i = 0, functionBody},
    count = Count[expression, PlusMinus, ∞, Heads -> True];
    tuples = Tuples[{Plus, Subtract}, count];
    functionBody = Replace[expression, PlusMinus :> Slot[++i], ∞, Heads -> True];
    Function[Evaluate@functionBody] @@@ tuples
]
```

Test results:

$a\pm b:$

```
test1 = a ± b;
distributePlusMinus[test1]
```

> ```
> {a + b, a - b}
> ```

$f(a\pm b):$

```
test2 = f[a ± b];
distributePlusMinus[test2]
```

> ```
> {f[a + b], f[a - b]}
> ```

$a\pm f(b\pm c):$

```
test3 = a ± f[b ± c];
distributePlusMinus[test3]
```

> ```
> {a + f[b + c], a + f[b - c], a - f[b + c], a - f[b - c]}
> ```

$a\pm b\pm f(c\pm d,e):$

```
test4 = a ± b ± f[c ± d, e];
distributePlusMinus[test4]
```

> ```
> {a+b+f[c+d,e],a+b+f[c-d,e],a-b+f[c+d,e],a-b+f[c-d,e],a+b-f[c+d,e],a+b-f[c-d,e],a-b-f[c+d,e],a-b-f[c-d,e]}
> ```

**Note:** These results depend on the fact that Mathematica splits up $a\pm b\pm c$ to $(a\pm b)\pm c$. Therefore, the algorithm needs adjustments for functions that do not exhibit this behavior. Especially, entering `PlusMinus[a,b,c]` is left as it is, while expressions involving $\pm$ are paired up as mentioned. The whole thing therefore works for the pretty-printed notation only.